# Copying files larger than 4Gb to Raspbmc Samba share

Tags: raspbmc

I cannot copy files larger than 4Gb to my Pi running Raspbmc using a Samba share. I get a message saying there is not enough space left on the destination, but that's not true. The client accessing the share is a Mac and the target filesystem is a ext3 USB drive.

How can I configure this Samba share to accept large files?

Comment: How is the samba share mounted? If you haven't specified that the filesystem is `ext3` then it may not have large file support enabled by default.

Comment: did you check the actual space left on the device? I had similar issues, and found that the pi was leaking memory after some dirty shutdowns.